# Bootstrap Endless Background Image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In this Layout:
[choose Agency-Demo,](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB02K3KK3)
they use a fullscreen background image. And when you begin to scroll, the background is overlayed by the content (div containers). When you scroll you can see that the background changes and is again overlayed by the following content.

How they find the correct positioning for the content depending on the screen size of the device?

And how they add different classes depending on the scroll-height?

Is it possible to do this with bootstraps standard functionality?

Comment: Are you just referring to the full width background images that stay fixed as you scroll? If so, that's just CSS' `background-attachment:fixed;`

Comment: No, especially I search for they way they do the initial positioning of the first overlaying div with the content "A THEME FOR CREATIVES & AGENCIES" (its not shown without scrolling) and how they replace the background (fullscreen image) depending on the document scroll-height. I prefer a only CSS way, if possible.

Comment: I'm confused because you refer to the  "A THEME FOR CREATIVES & AGENCIES"  section, which is just that, a section element with no background. It's not doing anything, but the background above it (and a little further down are just background images positioned as I mentioned above. There's nothing special being done and no scroll detection.

Comment: the special for me is that the position is in the non displayable part of the website. How they do that? They set the position depending on the screen size at begining? To the other part of my question I found scrollmagic.js which allows you to set css classes depending on the offset. Is there a build in support in bootstrap for this functionality.

Comment: Here's an example of what I think you're referring to: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2amjrjvu/light/. As for scrollmagic, Bootstrap doesn't have all of that functionality  built-in, in fact it has very little of it since that's a big plugin, but you can see on Bootstrap's JavaScript and Components pages what comes with it (e.g http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Comment: Thank you! Nice example...didn't expect that this is so easy. Is this a new functionality in css? How can I load all backgrounds at initial load and not at scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Agency-Demo is using the css cover selector. The cover keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions.
Results:
• Fills entire page with image, no white space
• Scales image as needed
• Retains image proportions (aspect ratio)
• Image is centered on page
• Does not cause scrollbars
• As cross-browser compatible as possible
• Isn't some fancy shenanigans like Flash

```
.demo-header {
text-align: center;
background: url('assets/img/bg-header.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
color: #fff;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background: cover;
padding: 100px 0;
}
```

For cross browser compatibility you can use the following code.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How they change there navbar? Can't find anything how they add the navbar-expanded class.